# Changing a searchbox to a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, xml

The searchbox matches the item names with those in an xml.  What I need to do is put these items in a drop down menu. I have been looking endlessly for a way to get the items from the xml without hardcoding in the html file. Here is my code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>

        <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse:collapse }
        td { padding:10px; border:solid #000 1px } 
        td.center { text-align:center }
        td.noBox { border:none }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var items;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // IE6, IE5
            var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","stock.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
        items=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item"); 


        function findItem() {
           var searchItem=document.getElementById("searchItem").value;
           for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
              product=items[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


              if (product==searchItem) {
                 id=items[i].getAttribute("id");
                 stockLevel=items[i].getElementsByTagName("numInStock")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                 price=items[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=id;
                 document.getElementById("stockLevel").innerHTML=stockLevel;
                 document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=price;
              }
           }
        }   

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <h1>Product list</h1>


        <script type="text/javaScript">
        document.write("<p>There are " + items.length + " items available</p>");
        </script>

        <table>
        <tr><th>id</th><th>Product</th><th>Stock level</th><th>Price</th></tr>
        <tr><td class="noBox" id="id"></td>

            <td><input type="select" size="20" id="searchItem" value="Enter item">
                <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="findItem()"></td>


            <td class="center" id="stockLevel"></td>
            <td class="center" id="price"></td>    
        </tr>
        </table>    

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're looking for is just to get information out of items array.

You'll need to just loop through the items array in javascript and add it to the select list.

Something like this should get you started:

```
<select id="dropdownlistofitems">
</select>

fillDropdown();
function fillDropdown(){
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
$('#dropdownlistofitems').append($('<option/>', { 
    value: value,
    text : value 
}));
});   
}
```

Comment: Is there a simpler solution? Even if you can explain it and I can try figure it out.